# Using scrapy to extract multiple data in table td elements

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and try to use it to extract the following data 
"name", "address", "state", "postal_code" from the sample html code below:

```
<div id="superheroes">
<table width="100%" border="0" ">
  <tr>
  <td valign="top">
  <h2>Superheroes in New York</h2>
  <hr/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td width="75%">                    
      <h2>Peter Parker</h2>
      <hr />
      <table width="100%">
        <tr valign="top">
          <td width="13%" height="70" valign="top"><img src="/img/spidey.jpg"/></td>
          <td width="87%" valign="top"><strong>Address:</strong> New York City<br/>
            <strong>State:</strong>New York<br/>
            <strong>Postal Code:</strong>12345<br/>
            <strong>Telephone:</strong> 555-123-4567</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="18" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right" valign="top"><a href="spiderman"><strong>Read More</strong></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <h2>Tony Stark</h2>
      <hr />
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" valign="top">
        <tr valign="top">
          <td width="13%" height="70" valign="top"><img src="/img/ironman.jpg"/></td>
          <td width="87%" valign="top"><strong>Address:</strong> New York City<br/>
            <strong>State:</strong> New York<br/>
            <strong>Postal Code:</strong> 54321<br/>
            <strong>Telephone:</strong> 555-987-6543</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="18" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right" valign="top"><a href="iron_man"><strong>Read More</strong></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="25%">
       <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
       </script>    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My superheroes.py contains the following code:

```
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from superheroes.items import Superheroes

items = []

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "superheroes"
  allowed_domains = ["www.somedomain.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://www.somedomain.com/ny"]
  rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')]

   def parse_item(self, response):
     sel = Selector(response)
     tables = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "superheroes")]/table/tr[2]/td[1]')
     for table in tables:
        item = Superheroes()
        item['name'] = table.xpath('h2/text()').extract()
        item['address'] = table.xpath('/tr[1]/td[2]/strong[1]/text()').extract()
        item['state'] = table.xpath('/tr[1]/td[2]/strong[2]/text()').extract()
        item['postal_code'] = table.xpath('/tr[1]/td[2]/strong[3]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
     return items
```

And my items.py contains:

```
import scrapy
class Superheroes(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
    state = scrapy.Field()
    postal_code = scrapy.Field()
```

When I ran "scrapy runspider superheroes.py -o super_db -t csv", the output file is empty.

Could anyone help me with any error in my code above?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your xpath expressions in `for` cycle and `yield` every item, instead of `return` array

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    tables = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "superheroes")]/table/tr[2]/td[1]')
    for name, data in zip(tables.xpath('./h2/text()'), tables.xpath('./table')):
        item = Superheroes()
        item['name'] = name.extract()
        item['address'] = data.xpath('.//strong[1]/text()').extract()
        item['state'] = data.xpath('.//strong[2]/text()').extract()
        item['postal_code'] = data.xpath('.//strong[3]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: @Daniil, thanks for your feedback! I got the following error when I run it: 
`ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //div[contains(@id, "superheroes")]/table/tr[2]/td[1]/`
Do you know what might causes this?

Comment: @Daniil, I found there's a "/" after the last element in xpath that causing the error. However the output is still empty. Do you know how to debug the scrapy - to see if it crawl to each page and scrap/extract the elements correctly? Thanks!

Comment: @M.Ridha for debug your spider take a look at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html . Can you add page url example to your question?

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues with your code. First, your `parse_item` method did not seem to be indented (at least, that's how it looks in your question), and thus would not be included in the MySpider class. Every line in superheroes.py starting at `def parse_item(self, response):` needs to have two spaces in front of it.

The second problem is that `rules` is stating that `parse_item` should be called for every link (i.e., `SgmlLinkExtractor`) found in the page. You can see in the output that it tries to fetch `/iron_man` and `/spiderman` -- those are the pages whose output would be passed to `parse_item`.

To process the `start_urls` with your `parse_item`, you need to rename it to `parse_start_url`. If there is is only one page which you'll be processing, you can even get rid of the `rules`! (see the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) about `parse_start_url`).

Your updated class looks like this (note that I also moved `items` inside of the method; there is no need to declare it as a global):

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "superheroes"
  allowed_domains = ["localhost"]
  start_urls = ["http://localhost:8000/page.html"]

  # indentation!
  def parse_start_url(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    headers = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "superheroes")]/table/tr[2]/td[1]/h2')
    for header in headers:
      item = Superheroes()

      item['name'] = header.xpath('text()')[0].extract()

      table = header.xpath('following-sibling::table')
      item['address'] = table.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/strong[1]/following-sibling::text()')[0].extract().strip()
      item['state'] = table.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/strong[2]/following-sibling::text()')[0].extract().strip()
      item['postal_code'] = table.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/strong[3]/following-sibling::text()')[0].extract().strip()

      yield item
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @Daniil Mashkin for pointing out that the original xpath expressions did not work. I corrected them in the code above. Cheers!

Comment: @Daniil's suggestion to get rid of `items = []` and `return items` and to replace `items.append(item)` with `yield item` is also excellent! I've updated my code accordingly

Comment: @DaniilMashkin hmm, you're right, I only briefly saw that the correct `name` was being output; there is no postal code nor state in the scrapy output. I'll fix the xpaths now. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg: thanks for your feedback! The parse_item method is now inside the class!

Comment: @M.Ridha please make sure to apply all the changes in my answer; I renamed your `parse_item` to `parse_start_url` and changed the XPaths